# Ajax JSON request object contains array, but the array is undefined on the server side. Strings are sent fine

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, express

I am creating a Node/Express app, and I am sending a JSON request from client to server-side (using body parser on the app). I am sending many Strings, all of which are are sent successfully and the server side can read their values. I am also trying to send an array containing a latitude and a longitude.

Debugging with IntelliJ, I can see that the client-side JSON object contains the array just before sending, and on the server side hovering over req.body shows my JSON object containing everything including the array.

However executing the code and trying to access the array, i encounter the error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Has anybody got any idea why this is happening? I don't understand why the IntelliJ debugger can see my array's values server-side, but executing the script throws the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to show the code, otherwise there's not much we can do. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You probably are passing the first item of words, instead of the array.

Instead, pass the array to the function
so if you've

```
hasWord("x",words[]);
```

you can write,

```
hasWord("x",words);
```

without the code I can only help this much.